# Using adjacency_matrix of Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost

I have to include `<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>` to build an adjacency_matrix, or the code will fail to compile.

I don't understand why, those examples I saw do not need it.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
using namespace boost;

typedef boost::adjacency_matrix< directedS > MatrixGraph;

int main(){
    const char* name = "ABCD";
    MatrixGraph mg(3);
    add_edge (0, 1, mg);
    add_edge (0, 3, mg);
    add_edge (1, 2, mg);
    add_edge (2, 3, mg);
    boost::print_vertices(mg,name);
}
```

Comment: Different versions of `boost` used in those examples may be?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to list the error message.

But I think I reproduced it on GCC 4.9 with Boost 1.58;

```
/home/sehe/custom/boost_1_58_0/boost/graph/detail/edge.hpp|111 col 10| error: ‘hash’ is not a class template
||    struct hash<boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<D, V> >
```

The fix is

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
```

Comment: Yes this is my error message. Thank you for your answer.